# npm dependency issue when installing... well, pretty much anything

Tags: node.js, npm, react-router

Suddenly, this is happening:

```
$ npm install history
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-76-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "history"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package history@1.13.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-router@1.0.3 wants history@^1.17.0
```

...when I try to install, well, pretty much anything. I've tried to install `react-bootstrap`, got this error, and tried to upgrade history. I'm not sure what to do here.

I've tried `npm i -S history@1.17.0` to no avail. Same error.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-loader": "1.0.9",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.6",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.1.0",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.5.0",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "node-sass": "3.4.2",
    "object-assign": "4.0.1",
    "react": "0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "4.4.0",
    "react-router": "2.0.0",
    "redux": "3.3.1",
    "redux-api-middleware": "1.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.0.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "1.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.5.1",
    "babel-core": "6.5.1",
    "babel-eslint": "5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.5.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.11.1",
    "chai": "3.4.1",
    "cheerio": "0.19.0",
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "cross-env": "1.0.7",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "eslint": "2.2.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.8.5",
    "mocha": "2.3.4",
    "node-sass": "3.4.2",
    "parallelshell": "2.0.0",
    "react-transform-catch-errors": "1.0.1",
    "react-transform-hmr": "1.0.1",
    "redbox-react": "1.2.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "0.13.0",
    "watch": "0.17.1",
    "webpack": "1.12.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.4.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.6.0",
    "yargs": "3.32.0"
  },
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you paste your package.json?

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: I tried this and it works, I am using node version `v4.2.4` and npm version `2.14.12`.

Comment: So odd - why am I getting this issue then? Do I need to uninstall and reinstall everything?

Comment: have you already run the command `npm install` , before installing any other modules ?

Comment: I prefer npm@3,  peerDep is just a warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like some versions had their wires crossed somehow. Ended up removing my node_modules directory `rm -r node_modules` and reinstalling `npm install` and that fixed it.

Comment: This is an incredibly subtle and annoying part of NPM's architecture. You might want to read up on [npm Non-determinism](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-nondet) (basically says that install order of deps affects your `node_modules` directory structure). The npm team claims that this dependency tree structure should not affect apps, but given your experience (and mine) I strongly suspect this is not actually true. It is not a bad idea to blast your `node_modules` folder from time to time and do a fresh install, particularly if you share your code or plan to do a remote install.