# Solving peer dependency issue in NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to satisfy the peer dependencies for different npm packages at the minute when I run `npm install`. This is the error message I appear to getting.

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package eslint@2.11.1 does not satisfy 
its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer eslint-config-airbnb@6.2.0 wants eslint@^2.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer eslint-plugin-mocha@2.2.0 wants eslint@^2.0.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer eslint-plugin-import@1.8.1 wants eslint@2.x
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer babel-eslint@5.0.4 wants eslint@<2.3.0
```

I have failed in a few attempts and cannot understand how to get to the solution here.

Comment: can you show your package.json ?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have eslint@2.11.1 installed globally ?

Try uninstall -g it, and run npm install again

Also look here

> Looks like some versions had their wires crossed somehow. Ended up
>   removing my node_modules directory rm -r node_modules and reinstalling
>   npm install and that fixed it.

[npm dependency issue when installing... well, pretty much anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323773/npm-dependency-issue-when-installing-well-pretty-much-anything/36327234)

---

> The error messages don't have to be related to the package you're
>   trying to install. That means, if you want to install e.g. kss the
>   error doesn't mean there is a problem with kss.
>
> Ok, so what? Check the additional messages prompted during the
>   installation attempt and find the packages that cause the problem. The
>   sections look like

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0 wants grunt@~0.4.0
```

https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-fix-npm-package-does-not-satisfy-its-siblings-peerdependencies-requirements

**Their solution is to either update or uninstall the modules.**